# onclicklistener for button array is giving null pointer

Tags: android, arrays, button, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I keep getting a nullpointer exception when I try to implement an onclicklistener for buttons I've created.

```
    Button setHighBtn[] = null;
    Button setLowBtn[]=null;
    TextView tv[] = new TextView[oNumber];
    for (int i=0;i<oNumber;i++){
        tv[i] = new TextView(this);
        tv[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv[i].setText(oName[i]);
        tv[i].setTextSize(20);
        //tv[i].setLayoutParam)
        layout.addView(tv[i]);
        if (capability[i]==0){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);               
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_capabilities, layout);   
            setHighBtn[i]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setHigh);
            setHighBtn[i]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setLow);
            setHighBtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);                             
            setLowBtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }else{
            setHighBtn[i]=null;                         
            setLowBtn[i]=null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a copy-paste error. You wrote:

```
setHighBtn[i]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setHigh);
setHighBtn[i]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setLow); //This is supposed to be setLowBtn[i]
```

Then you set a listener to `setLowBtn` which is not initialized yet. Edit it to:

```
setHighBtn[i]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setHigh);
setLowBtn[i]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setLow);
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect when wrote this?

```
Button setHighBtn[] = null;
Button setLowBtn[]=null;
```

Comment: thats not the problem. it wasn't even working before I added those lines. I added null cause for some iterations of the loop it won't create those buttons so I need to fill those spots in the array with null.